# reading multiple csv from different sub directories using map_df

Tags: r, csv

Hi I would need to download several csv files form several sub directories  and I would like to do it with map_df.

this is an example that I found online:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  list.files(path = "/Users/admin/apps/csv-courses/", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(.))
df
```

and I though I could change it like this since I would like to read the csv with object starting with the subfolder name:

```
common_path = "/home/documents/myfolder/mysubfolder"
primary_dirs = list.files(common_path);
primary_dirs # list of subfolders in mysubfolder
df <- list()
for(dir in primary_dirs) {
df[[paste0(i]] <-
  list.files(path = paste("/home/documents/myfolder/mysubfolder",dir), pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(.))
df[[paste0(i]] 
}
```

however, I get and empty list, sorry i dont have a more reproducible example but how can I read the csv file I want using this method?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any csv files here `/home/documents/myfolder/mysubfolder`? or are the files in further than that?

Comment: they are in primary dirs, that why i though I could loop for dir and set the path like ```path = paste("/home/documents/myfolder/mysubfolder",dir)```

Comment: You're iterative variable is `dir` yet you reference `i` in the for loop. Perhaps changing `i` to `dir` in your `paste0` would be a start in the right direction. As an aside I don't think it's necessary to include the paste0.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `recursive = TRUE` to your `list.files` function? This will let you list all csv files in sub directories. You might also need to add `full.names = TRUE`.

Comment: yes I changed the i to dir and added ```recursive=TRUE```and  ```full.names =TRUE```
but I still get the list with empty dataframes...I really don't know if there is an alternative to this method..

Comment: To be a clear, it should be added to your first line, no need for the for loop to build the file paths. `list.files(common_path, pattern = '*.csv', recursive= T, full.names = T)`

Comment: I added the loop because the files in the primary dirs have the exact same name.. and I would like the object from ```read.csv``` to have the folder name at the beginning...

Comment: @i.b   With R, you dont really need `for` loops